# SQL Server - query to return non-conflicting schedules

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to write a command to create schedules for employees with varying work addresses. There are a number of locations, each of which has to be visited once (by one employee) during a period.

To start, I've made just two tables, address_availability (columns avail_date and address) and employee_availability (columns avail_date and name)

To get a list of all possible placements, I just select the address and employee names from the two tables and join them on the date. As a sample output I get

```
London, Thomas, 27/05/2019
London, Thomas, 28/05/2019
Glasgow, Thomas, 27/05/2019
London, Mary, 27/05/2019
Glasgow, Mary, 27/05/2019
```

I need to make it so that there are no scheduling conflicts, i.e. if Thomas is proposed for London on the 27th he cannot be in Glasgow on the 27th.

I would also like to have the command give a maximum of 5 results per employee and not propose two employees for the same place on the same date.

I'm not really sure I'm using the right tool for the job. Is this doable in SQL ?

Comment: I'm not sure SQL Server is the right tool for this kind of job. This is something normally the application would handle; as it's going to (very likely) be an iterative process that's written back to the database once confirmed.

Comment: The idea was just to take the output into a spreadsheet. The effort to implement it in an application isn't really justified given how often it will be used so I might just revert to doing it manually if there's not some ready-made app that handles this kind of thing.

Comment: Too bad, I would have loved to see what one of the die-hards (100k+) could create here...  :) I think it's a great question in any case.

Comment: Even just for curiosity's sake or for future application where a non-conflicting result is required it would be interesting

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy to take it out into the spreadsheet, I would use a PIVOT query https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017) to get the data in a format

```
LOCATION     TIME        Thomas  Mary  

London       27/05/2019  1       1
Glasgow      27/05/2019  1       1

London       28/05/2019  1       0
```

So from the table above you can see that on the 27th Mary and Thomas can both do either but on the 28th Thomas is the only one available.

As for making it produce a list, you can take this script further by looping through and where there is only one option, taking it (and then removing that person for that day) and looping again. Depending on complexity you will soon hit limits where you have 2 options and you just need to take one.

This is also on the understanding that there is always a solution, you didn't layout the full requirements etc to suggest that.